# How autoplay embed youtube video in 2017?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I tied to use

```
var player;
player = new YT.Player('playerHome', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'deJWab2-xtc',
    playerVars: {
        controls: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        loop: 1,
        modestbranding: 1,
        rel: 0,
        showinfo: 0,
        nologo: 1,
        mute: 1
    },
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
    player.playVideo();
}
```

I tried `setVolume(0)` and `mute()`, but on iOS it not work. On Android and desktop browsers everything works fine.
Is there currently a working method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you mute the video before it is loaded

Try this:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
player.playVideo();
player.mute();
//setVolume(0); and this    
}
```